# Vim plugins on IdeaVim

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, vim-plugin, ideavim, ultisnips

I was using Vim in my computer, but recently I began using IntelliJ as IDE.
I was using some plugins in my Vim such as UltiSnips, vimtex, through vim-plug.
the problem is to transfer the plugins into IdeaVim in IntelliJ, I know about `.ideavimrc` file, it's filled with `source ~/.vimrc` and has path `~/.ideavimrc`. `~/.vimrc` file has content:

```
    call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
    Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
    filetype plugin indent on
    syntax enable
    let g:tex_flavor='latex'
    let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
    let g:vimtex_vew_general_viewer = 'okular'
    let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
    set conceallevel=1
    let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'
    Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
    Plug 'honza/vim-snippets' your text
    let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
    let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
    let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'
    let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical" 
    call plug#end()
```

Nevertheless plugins don't work in IdeaVim, but they work in Vim itself.

What can I do to make plugins work on IdeaVim?

Comment: IdeaVim is not a real Vim but its imitation. It is not meant to be compatible with Vim plugins.

Comment: so IdeaVim doesn't have some plugins which standard Vim has, am I right?

Comment: You have to experiment and see what works. There are some officially supported plugins https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/wiki/IdeaVim-Plugins

Comment: "officially supported" as in "completely rewritten".

Comment: They even use the path to real plugin repository as identificator, this is messed up and totally not confusing.